# How to foreach columns inside foreach rows

Tags: loops, laravel-5, laravel-blade

from the controller I have $rows I wanted to loop through columns inside $rows.

in php its just simple, but I wanted via laravel blade

```
@foreach($rows as $row)
<tr class="row" id="{{$row->id}}">
    @foreach($row as $column)
       <td>{{ $column }}</td>
    @endforeach
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Your question is not clearly, give details what you want to acheive and what you are trying to do

Comment: well, I am trying to get columns data from $row

Comment: Can you show what data is in your $rows array. @Ronald

Comment: @MuhammadShareyar thanks, my target a loop for different tables that contains "id".